# "OpenShiftCheckException", "Not all of the required packages are available at their requested version\norigin:3.10.0

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin, okd

I am installing OpenShift origin 3.10.0 and getting failure on below Ansible Task while running deploy_cluster.yml.

it was working fine for OpenShift origin 3.9.0

Environment:
VM with operating system version is CentOS 7.5

Currently when i run prerequisites.yml script it was run successfully for "*ansible-playbook -i inventory.ini openshift-ansible/playbooks/prerequisites.yml*"

Following is error trace

```
CHECK [memory_availability : x.0.x.x] **********************************
fatal: [x.x.x.x]: FAILED! => 
{  
   "changed":false,
   "checks":{  
      "disk_availability":{  
         "skipped":true,
         "skipped_reason":"Disabled by user request"
      },
      "docker_image_availability":{  
         "skipped":true,
         "skipped_reason":"Disabled by user request"
      },
      "docker_storage":{  
         "skipped":true,
         "skipped_reason":"Disabled by user request"
      },
      "memory_availability":{  
         "skipped":true,
         "skipped_reason":"Disabled by user request"
      },
      "package_availability":{  
         "changed":false,
         "invocation":{  
            "module_args":{  
               "packages":[  
                  "PyYAML",
                  "bash-completion",
                  "bind",
                  "ceph-common",
                  "cockpit-bridge",
                  "cockpit-docker",
                  "cockpit-system",
                  "cockpit-ws",
                  "dnsmasq",
                  "docker",
                  "etcd",
                  "firewalld",
                  "flannel",
                  "glusterfs-fuse",
                  "httpd-tools",
                  "iptables",
                  "ip 
tables-services",
                  "iscsi-initiator-utils",
                  "libselinux-python",
                  "nfs-utils",
                  "ntp",
                  "openssl",
                  "origin",
                  "origin-clients",
                  "origin-master",
                  "origin-node",
                  "origin-sdn-ovs",
                  "pyparted",
                  "python-httplib2",
                  "yum-utils"
               ]
            }
         }
      },
      "package_version":{  
         "failed":true,
         "failures":[  
            [  
               "OpenShiftCheckException",
               "Not all of the required packages are available at their requested version\norigin:3.10.0 \norigin-node:3.10.0 \norigin-master:3.10.0 \nPlease check your subscriptions and enabled repositories."
            ]
         ],
         "invocation":{  
            "module_args":{  
               "package_list":[  
                  {  
                     "check_multi":false,
                     "name":"origin",
                     "version":"3.10.0"
                  },
                  {  
                     "check_multi":false,
                     "name":"origin-master",
                     "version":"3.10.0"
                  },
                  {  
                     "check_multi":false,
                     "name":"origin-node 
",
                     "version":"3.10.0"
                  }
               ],
               "package_mgr":"yum"
            }
         },
         "last_failed":{  
            "failed":true,
            "invocation":{  
               "module_args":{  
                  "package_list":[  
                     {  
                        "check_multi":false,
                        "name":"origin",
                        "version":"3.10.0"
                     },
                     {  
                        "check_multi":false,
                        "name":"origin-master",
                        "version":"3.10.0"
                     },
                     {  
                        "check_multi":false,
                        "name":"origin-node",
                        "version":"3.10.0"
                     }
                  ],
                  "package_mgr":"yum"
               }
            },
            "msg 
":"Not all of the required packages are available at their requested version\norigin:3.10.0 \norigin-node:3.10.0 \norigin-master:3.10.0 \nPlease check your subscriptions and enabl 
ed repositories."
         },
         "msg":"Not all of the required packages are available at their requested version\norigin:3.10.0 \norigin-node:3.10.0 \norigin-master:3.10.0 \nPlease check your 
 subscriptions and enabled repositories."
      }
   },
   "msg":"One or more checks failed",
   "playbook_context":"install"
}
```

Comment: yum search origin cmd can check whether the required package find from your current repository.

Comment: @Daein  So it mean CentOS repos for 3.10.0 are not available right now? plz correct me if i am wrong? as this works fine for 3.9.0

Comment: I’ve searched about this issues, and I found the similar one: https://github.com/openshift/openshift-ansible/issues/8399 , they said the repository is not available yet.